# MATLAB: index a cell array with cell array of arrays and return a cell array

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

Say I have a cell array of (n X 1) vectors, `A`, and a cell array of vectors containing indices into `A`, called `B`.  I wish to extract a cell array, `C`, such that `C{i} = [A{B{i}}]`.
In other words, I have a cell array of arrays of indices, and I want to pull out the matrices corresponding to the concatenations of the vectors in `A` indexed by each of those arrays of indices.

```
for i = 1:length(B)
    %# B{i} is an array of indices, C{i} is a matrix
    C{i} = [ A{ B{i} } ];
end
```

The loop is equivalent to:

```
C = cellfun(@(x)[A{x}],B,'UniformOutput',false); %# implicit for loop w/ closure
```

Can I do that using an indexing expression alone?  Or at least without the loop?
I think `deal()` might have to be involved but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two alternative solutions:

- Collect all the indices of `B` together with the function [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html), index the contents of `A` to make one large matrix, then divide that matrix up using the function [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and the sizes of the index arrays in `B`:

  ```
  N = size(A{1});                        % Size of an array in A
  M = cellfun('prodofsize', B);          % Array of sizes of elements in B
  C = mat2cell([A{cell2mat(B)}], N, M);
  ```
- Here's a more compact version of your [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)-based solution:

  ```
  C = cellfun(@(x) {[A{x}]}, B);
  ```

Ultimately, I would decide what solution to use based on speed and readability, which may actually turn out to be your for-loop-based solution.

Comment: +1 Nice getting rid of 'UniformOutput','false'. What an eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:

```
C = A(cell2mat(B))
```

You may have a look at Loren's blog post about [Cell Arrays and Their Contents](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/)

Comment: This expression makes a cell array with each element a single vector from `A`.  I want to create a cell array with each element a matrix composed of vectors from `A` corresponding to the indices in an element of `B`.